# How to check that a value is NOT IN a %ROWTYPE from an SQL statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, rowtype

Im writing a PLSQL stored procedure. Note that the below is only a part of it and the actual SP is complex than this. All I want to know is that in my nested query below, how i can check a certain value is not in the ROWTYPE that i named as 'l_05_data' ? Is there a way to do it without running thourgh a loop. Currently i have no idea on how to make this check in my nested query because im getting the below error when compiling. Someone please provide a solution for this.

**

```
Error(52,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(66,41): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "l_05_data"."A2_ID_FK": invalid identifier
Error(66,51): PLS-00302: component 'A2_ID_FK' must be declared
```

**

stored procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  TEST_SP()
  AS

  TYPE r05_array IS TABLE OF A2_TBL%ROWTYPE;
    l_05_data r05_array;

    CURSOR r5_cur
    IS
      SELECT a2.* 
      FROM A2_TBL a2;
  BEGIN
    OPEN r5_cur;
    LOOP
    BEGIN

      FETCH r5_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_05_data LIMIT batch_limit;
      EXIT WHEN l_05_data.count() = 0;

      FOR indx IN l_05_data.FIRST ..l_05_data.LAST
      LOOP
            --some logic
      END LOOP;

      SELECT A1 BULK COLLECT
      INTO l_01_id_data
      FROM
        ( SELECT distinct column_value AS A1 FROM TABLE(l_01_id_data)
        MINUS
        (
          SELECT distinct a1.A1_ID
          FROM A1_TBL a1
          INNER JOIN A2_TBL a2
          ON a1.A1_ID = a2.A2_A1_ID_FK
          WHERE  a2.A2_STATUS !='X' 
          OR (a2.A2_A1_ID_FK NOT IN (l_05_data.A2_A1_ID_FK) AND a2.A2_STATUS = 'X')
          )
        );   
           COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        --exception is handled here

    END;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE r5_cur;

  END TEST_SP;
```

below is the two table schema used in the SP
[image]

Comment: Is `l_05_data.A2_ID_FK` an actual table.field value? with _FK on the end its more like its a Foreign Key? Can you `DESC A2_TBL` and include that in the question please.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A2_TBL is linkedin with  A_TBL with the foreign key A2_ID_FK.

Comment: Is A2_ID_FK the name of a field, or the name of the Foreign Key Constraint?

Comment: A2_ID_FK is name of a field in the A2_TBL

Comment: This is really difficult to work with without the schema's being included within the question - it would be useful for them to be added `TYPE r05_array IS TABLE OF ABC_TABLE%ROWTYPE;` thats declaring the type for the l_05_data, but we have no information on the schema of abc_table either

Comment: The DDL for all the tables involved might help, but there's a lot of other stuff missing. I think your underlying problem is that you can't treat `l_05_data` as a table in your query because it's a PL/SQL table not a schema-level collection type, right? A realistic [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would probably be useful, but I think you're going to need a different approach.

Comment: I have edit the post with schema details

Comment: Sounds like you want something similar to `member of` for a single attribute of a collection of plain PL/SQL records. There's nothing like that built in I'm afraid. You might be able to write your own function, but mixing it with SQL could get tricky.

Comment: may be i can write the required temporary data to a table and use it without trying to access the %ROWTYPE within the SQL. I'll try in that way. Thank you